# Failed to boot STM32mp157a-dk1 using a buildroot image

Tags: linux, ext4, u-boot, buildroot, mmc

I'm trying to boot an STM32MP157a-dk1 using an image that i made with buildroot but when i boot i got this message :

Unable to write "/uboot.env" from mmc0:4
[image]

Help me please !!

H.M

Comment: Have you tried to create your ext4 filesystem without `metadata_csum` and `64bit`? 
Example [here](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/STM32MP1/) (search for "mkfs.ext4 >= 1.43")

Comment: in my project i have create my partitions with the genimage.cfg : 
image sdcard.img {
 hdimage {
  gpt = "true"
 }

 partition fsbl1 {
  image = "%ATFBIN%"
 }

 partition fsbl2 {
  image = "%ATFBIN%"
 }

 partition ssbl {
  image = "u-boot.stm32"
 }

 partition rootfs {
  image = "rootfs.ext4"
  bootable = "yes"
 }
}

Comment: I guess it should be a different config, have a look at the option `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_MKFS_OPTIONS` in line 18 [here](https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/configs/stm32mp157a_dk1_defconfig?h=50de52ae693b4d22e1275d98382de7b66baa0d78#n18).

Comment: yes it works i changed in my configs the ext2_mkfs_options thank you

Comment: Done !! thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed in my configuration via the menuconfig and in the EXT2_MKFS_OPTIONS I used:-O ^metadata_csum,^64bit.